# TypeError: jQuery(...).placeholder is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I use the avada theme, version 3.6.1. and runnig WP 4.5.5.

Some calenders weren't showing on the website and the error was: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: `a[href*=#]:not([href`

I changed the `main.js [href*=#] into [href*="#"]`

Now Im getting this:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).placeholder is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (4b8c4.js:1792)
>       at i (26ef1.js:5)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (26ef1.js:5)
>       at Function.ready (26ef1.js:5)
>       at HTMLDocument.K (26ef1.js:5)

Comment: It looks like you upgraded something that gave you a new set of jQuery/plugins and you don't have the placeholder plugin anymore

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna update the `placeholder` attribute, you need to use `attr` method.

```
$('[href*="#"]').attr('placeholder', 'hoge');
```

Comment: it now says:  jQuery('input, textarea').placeholder();

what should I edit?

Comment: You need to check if the jQuery Placeholder plugin is loaded or not.